# Показ сообщения об ошибке

Tags: delphi

Как сделать в дельфи 7 так, чтобы после нажатия кнопки появлялось окно, аналогичное ошибке с моим текстом, затем после нажатия "ок" ещё одно такое окно и после нажатия "ок" во втором окне приложение закрывалось.

Comment: [Повтор вопроса](http://hashcode.ru/questions/106324/).

Answer (score 1):

Вы хоть читали справку по Delphi? Перехвати исключение, вызови одну, две... пять форм, и на последней поставь процедуру завершения проги. Код давать не буду, сам найдешь в сети. (Полезно для мозга).

Answer (score 0):

Привет попробуй так (если я правильно понял, что тебе нужно):

```
if MessageDlg('Твое сообщение об ошибке 1', mtError, mbOK, 0) = mrOk then
    if MessageDlg('Твое сообщение об ошибке 2', mtError, mbOK, 0) = mrOk then
        Close();
```

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку в этом месте mbOK, 0) = mrOk

Comment: возьми mbOK в квадратные скобки [], т.е:

MessageDlg('Твое сообщение об ошибке 1', mtError, [mbOK], 0)